# Posição de "letra" em string

Tags: lua

Como posso fazer para pegar a posição de uma letra em uma string.
EX:

```
 a = "x  x  x"
```

Gostaria de pegar a posição de cada x.
Tentei usa o string.find, mas ele só pegou a da primeira.

Comment: Qual o problema real que você está tentando resolver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = "x  x  x"

pos = 0
while 1 do
    pos = a:find( "x", pos + 1 )
    if not pos then break end
    print( pos )  -- poderia armazenar numa tabela
end
```

Saída:

```
1
4
7
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/nJcPvI)**.

Answer (score 3):

Tente também

```
a = "x  x  x"
for k in a:gmatch("()x") do
    print(k)
end
```

Note a captura vazia `()`, que captura a posição.

Comment: Estava torcendo pra ver a sua solução, para ver se tinha maneiras mais elegantes de resolver. +1   @GabrielSales, considere a possibilidade de considerar esta como aceita. Segue um teste no IDEONE: http://ideone.com/S754jh